# Visual Styles within Dialog Based MFC Applications?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, winapi, mfc

The MFC Application Wizard disables visual styles for dialog based applications.

- But why?
- Regardless of the wizard, can I still use the visual styles in my dialog based application (it includes toolbar and menubar)?

Thank you!

[image: MFC Application Wizard]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's a little confusion here.

The greyed out drop-down is title "Visual Styles and colors" in my English version of VS2008. Being greyed out means that you can't modify its value, but it still reports that the resulting app will use "Windows Native/Default".  When you go on and create the app and run it, themes are fully supported.

For the other application type options (single document, multiple document, multiple top-level documents), and select other non-system themes.  The list is: Office 2003, VS 2005, Office 2007 of various different colors.

So whilst you don't get these non-standard Office themes, your app will have visual styles and themes as determined by the Windows settings.

Comment: @David Heffernan: Yes, by default it's using "Windows Native/Default" but can I make my dialog-based app using another style for example "VS 2005"? If I select the radio button "dialog based", the Combo Box switches back to "Windows Native/Default". What do you mean with "themes are fully supported"?

Comment: @Christian You can't use the non-system themes for dialog based. But you get visual styles (a.k.a. XP themes).

Comment: @Christian To elaborate on "themes are fully supported" I mean that you get XP themes, Aero etc. You are not restricted to Windows Classic. By themes I am using a commonly used synonym for what is officially known by MS as [Visual Styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773187(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: @David: I understand, thanks for the link! I have to look how I can enable the Visual Styles, because my app looks like the first image on the site of your link.

Comment: @Christian Mine looked like the second image! Which theme are you using in Windows? If you are using Windows Classic then that would explain it.

Comment: @David: It doesn't depend on the Windows theme, classic or xp-theme, the buttons don't have rounded corners and the selected button doesn't have this light blue frame (even if I switch to the standard xp theme).

Comment: @David: Now it works, if I create a new Project with previously switched to the xp-theme, the app looks modern.

Comment: @David: I found the reason: It depends on the UNICODE project settings. If UNICODE is disabled, the app looks like Windows 98! [Here is an explanation](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vcgeneral/thread/90256ddb-0abf-40cb-96b6-8e680ad8f76d)

Comment: @Christian Ah, I remember seeing hints at that in some of the websearches I did but I forgot to mention it in my answer. Anyway, sounds like you are in business again.

Comment: Is this "disabled/non-changable" value present in the properties pane? I can't see it any where :(